# C/C++: Naming conventions for arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, naming-conventions

What is a good naming convention for arrays? I am working on a code base with few thousand line of codes and there is no consistent naming convention for arrays. Few ppl name them by appending **List** at the end of the name like ***message_list***, which I really dont like as it wrongly suggests that this is a list(linked list), and few people name them by appending 's' at the end like ***messages*** which is better than previous approach but sometimes fails.

I want to know if there are any naming conventions out there for array type variables?

Comment: My vote goes for a plural 's'. Anyways, voting to close as subjective. Just choose one for your code base and be **consistent** with it.

Comment: @Xeo: This question is not subjective. I am not asking which naming convention is better. I am merely asking if there are any naming conventions out there and if there are, what are they? I will decide for my self which I like better.

Comment: Naming conventions at their core are subjective. And if you're not asking which is better, then you're just requesting a list of all naming conventions, which is off-topic here. That question is far too open-ended and quickly devolves into a dreaded poll. Just make up whatever you like and stick with it. That's honestly all that matters.

Comment: The term "better" implies subjective, as *better* is defined "in the eyes of the beholder".

Answer (score 8):

Name them for what they hold.  An array of messages should be called `messages`.  An array of file names should be called `filenames`.  Capitalize to suit your whims and prejudices.

There are those who argue for the singular, suggesting that `message[i]` is singular and better than `messages[i]`.  There is some justice in that, but the counter-argument is that the variable names an aggregate, so the plural is better.

I'd not use a suffix such as `_list` for an array.

Comment: +1: "Capitalize to suite your whims and prejudices."

Answer (score 3):

A naming convention we had at a previous job I worked at was variables started with some letter to indicate their scope (m_ for member variables, a_ for parameters, etc).  Then after the underscore was another letter or two indicating the type (_p for pointers, _dw for ints (dword), _s for strings, etc) then the variable name.  You could just adopt something similar to this, all that really matters is your code is readable to your convention, so you could start all of your arrays with something like `a_VariableName` to say that since it starts with an `a_` it is an array

Comment: Honestly, I got so used to it that I find code without it a little hard to read

Comment: dwords are, of course, not integers.

Comment: an `int` is a dword though...in most compilers

Comment: Not in the Windows world. `DWORD` is always an unsigned int.

Comment: Yeah, I recall now that we did use it for unsigned ints, but we also did most of our programming in PS3

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use "primitive" containers directly.  Rather, most often, the array (or vector) is a member in a "real" class that is a "first-class-citizen" that logically identifies some logical aggregate.  Thus, the name of the array is an obvious data-member name for the class:

```
class MyCritters
{
private:
  std::vector<Critter> critter_set_;
  //...or...
  Critter[10] critter_set_;
};
```

This has the added advantage that I have "intercept points" to perform logical set operations, ensure non-NULL, ensure uniqueness, add type-specific iteration algorithms, etc.

However, if I *were* to simply use an array directly, I typically append "set" to name.  On my system, I have common interface functions for arrays, vectors, linked lists, etc., and those are all (ordered) sets.  Thus, "set" will always be correct, and I can simply change the definition (instantiation), and all the other accessors still work correctly.

Comment: A mathematical set has no duplicates; arrays in general can have duplicates.  I'd not use `_set` as a suffix unless the array was constrained to be a mathematical set without duplicate entries.

Comment: @Jonathan, somewhat agree, but "set" is a standardized interface where the implementation may be "vector" or "linked-list".  Change type, and recompile, interface does not change. By our convention, `MyCritters` is *known* to be a unique collection of `Critter` instances, while we typically *also* have `MyCritterSet` (as the data-member within `MyCritters`) which is *not* enforced to be a unique collection, may contain NULL, and may actually be implemented as a `vector` or `linked-list` (as an implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the plural of whatever object the array contains. Generally, specifying the type of the variable in its name is considered bad practice, but if you want though, you could try using [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), so something like `arrPrimeNumbers`.

Comment: [Stroustrup's opinion](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#Hungarian) on Hungarian Notation.